schehecheyanu and netilat yadaim
My wife made a new Netilat Yadaim cup in her pottery workshop, which turned out really beautiful and very nicely decorated. I am eager to say the shehecheyanu blessing the first time I perform a mitzva with it. I follow the ashkenazi minhag, so I first wash my hands, then say the netilat yadaim blessing, and after that I dry my hands.
The question is: when do I say the shecheyanu blessing?

Before the washing (i.e. before actually performing the mitzva)
After the washing of hands, but before the drying (I suppose, in this case, it should follow after the netilat yadaim blessing, since the first one is more common).
After the drying of hands (although, I really see no strong reasoning for this choice)


It's unclear to me why a shehechiyanu blessing is warranted at all.

The classical case for asking this question is on a new fruit. Do you say sheecheyanu before or after the blessing on the fruit. Here there is no reason to say the blessing at all.
